# Python --version says version 3.10.8 but error when installing whisper says I have version 3.11.2

Tags: debian, kali-linux

So I'm trying to install whisper from OpenAI and says I have version `3.11.2` so it can not install whisper which requires only versions `>=3.7,<3.11`  But I swear when I check my python version it says I have the one I need, like this:

```
$ python --version                                      
Python 3.10.8
```

Btw Before I had version `3.11.2` but I changed it with help from [this post](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-switch-python-version-in-ubuntu-debian/) 
Maybe doing the commands from this post didn't help.
I'm a total begginner so maybe there is a simple solution which I don't kow. Also I'm using kali linux.
Down here is the error I have:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Collecting git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
      Cloning https://github.com/openai/whisper.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-n6ajw2le
      Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/openai/whisper.git /tmp/pip-req-build-n6ajw2le
      Resolved https://github.com/openai/whisper.git to commit ad3250a846fe7553a25064a2dc593e492dadf040
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Collecting triton==2.0.0
      Using cached triton-2.0.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (63.3 MB)
    Collecting numba
      Using cached numba-0.56.4.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [8 lines of output]
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
            File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
            File "/tmp/pip-install-bvqf8ryy/numba_26a7eac980d84443948e159a452af5d2/setup.py", line 51, in <module>
              _guard_py_ver()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-bvqf8ryy/numba_26a7eac980d84443948e159a452af5d2/setup.py", line 48, in _guard_py_ver
              raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))
          RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.11.2; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported.
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: I posted the code in this terribly. I will edit it if I can. Although the problem is what I wrote at the start. First time in this forum, sorry.

Comment: If you run ` python3 --version`  what do you get? Also (maybe this is not problem as the error says) but you can try running: `pip3 install` instead of `pip install`.

Comment: When I run ` python3 --version` it says: └─$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
Also, I tried pip3 install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
And I got the same error

Comment: ` python3 --version ` says I have version 3.11.2 and └─$ pip3 install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git   gives me the same error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the command should be `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3` (backup /usr/bin/python3 in case this one is not a symlink, make the backup by using `cp /usr/bin/python3 /home/youruser/`)

Comment: Oh! Like that it finally installs! Although the second command about the backup, cp /usr/bin/python3 /home/youruser/)  didn't work because I don't have a home partition. I just installed kali_linux 3  days ago and the recommended from kali install was to use only 1 partition from beginners. But I think I'll change that. Should I use a separate home partition or home, var and tmp? Anyways with your last comment, is done. When I reinstall the OS for the home partition I should be able to install whisper easily in the new OS. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that! About your Linux installation are you using the root user? Because what **use only 1 partition from beginners** means is that all the system will be installed in one partition instead of using `/home` `/var` etc partition scheme. Maybe the command failed because you used literally `/home/youruser/` you should replace `youruser` with your username (run `echo $USER` to get it)

Comment: Anyways, the problem seems to be related to python code from the git repo since this one is checking `python3` which was a symlink to the incorrect python version. Maybe the answer given by `@xiota`  could help to solve the problem too. And btw, If you have any problems with running `whisper` in Kali I would suggest you use another distribution since Kali might not have the necessary packages/repositories to download some dependencies. But if you want to learn cybersecurity/hacking tools then you can use Kali in a VM or in dual boot.

Comment: Haha I took it literal and didn't write user xD I will install ubuntu and use kali in a virtual box, as you said. Thanks a lot man, you were a great help!

Comment: You're wlecome! Have a nice day

Comment: As you've resolved the issue, please do [write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) describing the steps you took, and later [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. You'll find [guidelines for answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help). I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking at least the Asking and Answering -sections in the Help to learn how the site works. Reviewing some questions with accepted answers is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `update-alternatives` is the other versions are still installed and the programs you're using don't necessarily have to use the version you want them to.  Try removing unwanted packages with `apt purge`.

Also, look in `~/.local/bin` and `~/.local/lib` to remove Python-related junk that `pip` leaves behind.  If you didn't install anything else in those folders, they should be safe to delete.  Warning: `~/.local/share` does contain files you will want to keep.  If you want to clean it up, you'll have to go through it manually.

`pip` caches downloads in `~/.cache/pip`, so you can reinstall packages without having to redownload most of them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The forum user ' Edgar Magallon' helped me in the comments, but your answer was very educational. Thank you again! Sadly I can't upvote until I have 15 reputation, I wanted to upvote you.